# Combine JSON and String in a dictionary with Swifty

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, swifty-json

I'd like to create a JSON object in Swifty that has the form:

```
{
    "store": {
        "id": {
            "test": "test"
        },
        "type": "retail",
        "name": "store1"

    }
}
```

Is there a way to combine types in a Dictionary to use with Swifty (String and JSON)?  Quotes works, but when I try to assign a variable, it complains: `Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'JSON?'`:

```
func jsonTest()->String {
    var storeJson = [String: JSON]()
    var someJson = JSON(["test":"test"])
    storeJson["id"] = someJson
    storeJson["type"] = "retail" // <-- works fine
    var name = "store1"
    storeJson["name"] = name // <-- Doesn't work
    var store = JSON(storeJson)
    return store.rawString()!
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason

```
storeJson["type"] = "retail"
```

works differently than

```
storeJson["name"] = name
```

is because the first one follows a different path in the code. Specifically, it uses the `init(stringLiteral value: StringLiteralType)` method in the following extension ([source](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift#L551)).

```
extension JSON: Swift.StringLiteralConvertible {

    public init(stringLiteral value: StringLiteralType) {
        self.init(value)
    }

    public init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: StringLiteralType) {
        self.init(value)
    }

    public init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: StringLiteralType) {
        self.init(value)
    }
}
```

I'll explain further after we talk about how to fix your specific problem.

### <strike>Possible solution #1</strike>:

```
storeJson["name"]?.string = name
```

Output:

```
{
  "id" : {
    "test" : "test"
  },
  "type" : "retail"
}
```

The reason

```
storeJson["name"]?.string = name
```

doesn't work as we might think is because of the optional chaining. Right now, if we ran this through the debugger, we wouldn't see anything meaningful. In fact, we would see *nothing*. This is a bit concerning and likely means `storeJson["name"]` is `nil`, so the statement is not executing any further. Let's verify our hypothesis by making it blow up. We'll change the line to:

```
storeJson["name"]!.string = name
```

In this case, with your current code, you'll likely get

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

as you should because `storeJson["name"]` is in fact `nil`. Therefore, **this solution doesn't work**.

### Possible solution #2:

As you correctly noted in your answer, if you add a `storeJson["name"] = JSON(name)`, you'll get the desired behavior:

```
func jsonTest()->String {
    var storeJson = [String: JSON]()
    var someJson = JSON(["test":"test"])
    storeJson["id"] = someJson
    storeJson["type"] = "retail" // <-- works fine
    var name = "store1"
    storeJson["name"] = JSON(name) // <-- works!
    var store = JSON(storeJson)
    return store.rawString()!
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "id" : {
    "test" : "test"
  },
  "name" : "store1",
  "type" : "retail"
}
```

Great! Therefore, **this solution works**! Now, later in your code you can alter it however you want using `.string` and the like.

### Explanation

Back to why the string literal works. You'll notice in the `init`, it has

```
self.init(value)
```

which passes through the objects [`init`](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift#L87), which then goes through the [case statement](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift#L156)

```
        ...
        case let string as String:
            _type = .String
            self.rawString = string
        ...
```

When you call `storeJson["name"] = JSON(name)`, you're skipping the `StringLiteralType` `init` and simply going into the `switch`.

Therefore, you could interchange

```
storeJson["type"] = "retail"
```

with

```
storeJson["type"] = JSON("retail")
```

Comment: See https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift#L811. It converts it to an `NSString`. Hmm, interesting that it isn't working for you... give me a sec to check this out.

Comment: Ok this is an extension of the JSON object built into Swifty

Comment: Right. You should be able to do this though. See: http://oss.io/p/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.

Comment: Yeah that's strange its not working.  I wonder if there is a difference of type between when it is in `"quotes"` and when it is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it works to change:

`storeJson["name"] = name`

to

`storeJson["name"] = JSON(name)`